# Apollo Client error when executing a mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Here again for another question which I can't seem to figure out.

I am using Apollo Client (with react) to communicate with my GraphQL server.

I get an error when I try to perform a mutation and I don't know where the issue is coming from because other mutations work fine.

This is the mutation I'm having an issue with:

```
const DELETE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation deleteUser($id: ID!) {
        deleteUser(id: $id) {
            id
        }
    }
`;
```

The mutation works fine when I input it in the GraphQL playground...

This is how I call the mutation (triggered by a button click):

```
<button
    onClick={() =>
        deleteUser({
            variables: {
                id: user.id,
            },
        })
    }>
```

Note: `user.id` is obtained by performing a query and it is valid.

Finally, this is how the deleteUser function is defined (using the `useMutation` hook)

```
const [deleteUser, { error }] = useMutation(DELETE_USER_MUTATION, {
    refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_USERS_QUERY }],
});
```

On a side note, how can one debug such errors? On the console I get an error 400, which I read means that it's probably an error with the mutation itself. But I don't get more information about the error... I tried to catch it but to no avail.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue and I can't believe I didn't realize the problem sooner.

After checking the type of user.id, I realized it was a string instead of an integer. Converting it to a an Int worked.

However I'm having some cache issues now... Time for more research